# 2x50w stereo vs 100w mono amplifier efficiency

Tags: batteries, amplifier, speakers, efficiency, portable

Which is better for efficiency.

1. mono 100w amplifier

   or
2. stereo 2x50w

It is important because I'am building a portable speaker and it is really important for me to use little power.

Also which will sound louder? Or is it about the same?

Comment: Not enough information. If both amplifiers use the same architecture or circuit topology, there will be no difference in nominal efficiency. On the other hand, a class-D amplifier will be a lot more efficient than, say, a class-B amplifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watt doesn't have much to do with efficiency. You could have an amplifier that dissipates 100W of power but only output 45W to the speakers (low efficiency), or you could have one that puts over 90W to the speakers.

As Dave already said, if you want a portable system look into Class D amplifiers. You'll find a lot of pre-build class D amplifier modules for cheap if you are willing to order from china.

Regarding perceived volume: 50W and 100W are almost equal in volume. To double the perceived volume you have to multiply the watts by ten (rule of thumb). That's due to the logarithmic way we humans perceive volume.

For your portable amp the efficiency of the speaker is likely much more important than the raw wattage of the amplifier stage.